# Find most recent scp files

Tags: ssh, history, scp

A few weeks ago I scp'd some files to my computer from a friend's computer for future use. Now I want to use those files, but I can't remember where I put them and I have looked all over. Is there some sort of history of the scp's made into my computer?

I have looked in `/var/log/auth.log` with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 suggestions:

## 1) Check you bash history

This can be done by opening the file `~/.bash_history` with e.g. Gedit (or any other text editor you prefer) and searching for the command `scp` so as to see where you chose to save those files.

## 2) Find your files with a search utility

If the 1st suggestion doesn't work because you use very frequently the terminal and so these entries have been overwritten I would suggest either using the command `find` or the command `locate`. In any case, you have to remember the filenames of the files, or at least part of them.

I know the `locate` command better myself and I find it quicker, so I will describe on how to do it using it.

First of all, open a terminal by hitting `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type in:

```
sudo updatedb
```

and then give

```
locate *thecharactersIknow*
```

where `thecharactersIknow` is the part of the filename that you remember. For example, if you remember `hi_there` while the real filename is `hello_hi_there.jpg`, then you should give

```
locate *hi_there*
```

Also, if you are sure that the files are stored under your home directory, you can filter your results, like this:

```
locate *hi_there* | grep $USER
```

or similarly...